# TypeError: input expected at most 1 arguments, got 3 error

Tags: python

**Hello,**

I was messing around with some code when I started to run it and get the error "TypeError: input expected at most 1 arguments, got 3"

The snippit of the code that is giving me the issue is

[The snippit of code giving me the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/einRx.png)

Anyone know how I can fix it?

Comment: Please see [Why may I not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. The `input()` function expects at most one arg as its prompt string, but you're trying to give it three strings. You can't do that.

Answer (score 1):

When you ask if the inputted username is correct, you have a if for `yes`, `no` and an else. In that else you don't use `input()` which requires only 1 argument. But you provide 3. Concatenating the string will fix it

Answer (score 0):

that mean you must add 1 argument not 3

example

```
def main(lol):

  print lol
```

and i need to add 1 arguments for it work

```
lol = 'lol'

main(lol)
```

but if add  3 arguments

```
hey = 'hey'
ok = 'ok'
main(lol, hey, ok)
```

it will give the same error so you should add 1 argument not 3